# CakePHP: pagination with recursive queries not working as expected

Tags: cakephp, pagination, recursive-query

I got this models:

```
class CompanyRestaurantRequest extends AppModel
{
    public $name = "CompanyRestaurantRequest";      
    //public $actsAs = array('Containable');        
    public $hasMany = array(
        "UserRestaurantRequestFeed" => array(
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}

class UserRestaurantRequestFeed extends AppModel{
    public $name = "UserRestaurantRequestFeed";         
    public $belongsTo = array("CompanyRestaurantRequest");
    public $hasMany = array("UserRestaurantRequestFeedResponse");
}

class UserRestaurantRequestFeedResponse extends AppModel{
    public $name = "UserRestaurantRequestFeedResponse";

    public $belongsTo = array("UserRestaurantRequestFeed");

}
```

and I am trying to paginate CompanyRestaurantRequest like this:

```
$this->CompanyRestaurantRequest->recursive = 5;
$this->CompanyRestaurantRequestFeed->recursive = 5;
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => array(
             'CompanyRestaurantRequest.id' => 'desc'
    )
);
$this->set('requests', $this->paginate("CompanyRestaurantRequest"));
```

The problem is that I get no CompanyRestaurantRequestFeedResponse.

I tried to attach ContainableBehavior to the CompanyRestaurantRequest model and I used **contain** key in paginate settings like this:

```
'contain' => array('CompanyRestaurantRequestFeedResponse');
```

Anything I try, I can not get those CompanyRestaurantRequestFeedResponses related to CompanyRestaurantRequestFeeds.

How can I make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Intead of lines:

```
$this->paginate = array(
  'limit' => 10,
  'order' => array(
         'CompanyRestaurantRequest.id' => 'desc'
  )
);
```

At the top of the Controller where all var are declared add:

```
public $paginate = array(
  'CompanyRestaurantRequest' => array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => array(
      'CompanyRestaurantRequest.id' => 'desc'
    )
  )
);
```

This should fix it...

Comment: I have respected the conventions of this framework entirely. And the proof of that is the fact that I can retreive data at the level of recursivity I need when I use $Model->find(). The className anf the foreignKey are "known" implicitely if conventions are respected, as I know. If you have any other sugestions I would be grateful. Thank you!